# Assigning OnClick listener from a super fragment to a new activity

Tags: android

I am trying to assign OnClick listener of an ImageView in a new class.

Problem:
The problem is that the Fragment class is not `open` which cant be inherit. I am adding a new component located in the `fragment_home.xml`. I can only inherit the super activity, so I wanted to know if it possible to assign the listener from a new activity? I have tried the following and it just crashed the app...

`NewActivity.kt`

```
class MainActivity : SuperMainActivity() {
    ...
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val abcImageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.abc)
        abcImageView?.setOnClickListener { Todo() }
    }
}
...
```

`fragment_home.xml`

```
...
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/abc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/abc"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    android:src="@drawable/abc" />
...
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
When I click on the ImageView, it shows the `run` log like this...

```
I/ViewRootImpl@91838a8[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@91838a8[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
```

Comment: Sorry for asking but why would you do this?

Comment: @SlothCoding I just want to follow the original theme, I don't want to recreate the whole thing as it will look like a mess. Plus the super class fragment is locked, only the XML is accessible

Comment: Can you provide your log? What error was shown once your app crashed?

Comment: Actually, I just found out the one that cause crash is that I use abc.setOnClickListener instead of abc?.setOnClickListener

Edit: now it have no error but it seems to be not working. tested with Toast.makeText but shows nothing when click

Comment: And what is your Todo() function?

Comment: the todo function wil redirect url to the default browser. that's all

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if we can pass a function directly, but passing an object is possible. So wrapping the `onClickListener` within a class and implementing `Parcelable` must do the trick

Try the following

```
@Parcelize
class TransposableClickListener(val clickListener : () -> Unit) : Parcelable{
   fun onClick() = clickListener()
}
```

Now you can try something like,

```
//base activity class

val intent = Intent(context, NextActivity::class.java);
var bundle = Bundle()
val transposableClickListener = TransposableClickListener(::ToDo)
bundle.putParcelable("clickListener",transposableClickListener)
intent.putExtra("myBundle",bundle)
startActivity(intent);
```

```
//destination activity class
val bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("myBundle")
var clickListener = bundle.getParcelable<TransposableClickListener>("clickListener") as TransposableClickListener

//usage will be
textview.setOnClickListener{
clickListener.onClick()
}
```